# How to yank without a buffer?

Tags: vimscript, cut-copy-paste

Does any kind of `:call yank(register_name, "string")` API exist in vim? Or at least `:yank register_name "strings"` - I can't find any way to yank in vimscript without modifying a VIM buffer.

Comment: Are you talking about registers or buffers?

Comment: @romainl buffers

Comment: Not sure how buffers are involved, here.

Comment: @JoL yeah, that sort of makes sense but also not really. Color me puzzled.

Comment: @romainl because the only way I know how to yank text is to put it in a buffer and then use `y` or `:yank`

Comment: I would recommend you go through the user manual: `:help user-manual`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help setreg()`

It's precisely `:call setreg(register_name, "string")`